# JavaFX Exception in Application start method

Tags: java, fxml

Following [Javafx and Intellij : Non-modular with maven](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) I'm facing a problem at the start of the project

```
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:run (default-cli) @ diamond.server ---
Exception in Application start method
Exception in Application stop method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Julien/Documents/Project/diamond.server/diamond.server/target/classes/ctrl/partiesManagement.fxml:21
```

I don't understand what causing this problem and I can't find it, everything seems to be ok for me...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}

static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
    scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
}

private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Ctrl.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
    return fxmlLoader.load();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    scene = new Scene(loadFXML("partiesManagement"));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    refWrk.startServer(PORT);
}
```

Here is my partiesManagement.fxml where is linked to the Java Class CtrlParties.

```
<VBox alignment="CENTER"
      maxHeight="-Infinity"
      maxWidth="-Infinity"
      minHeight="-Infinity"
      minWidth="-Infinity"
      prefHeight="400.0"
      prefWidth="600.0"
      spacing="10.0"
      **xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"**
      fx:controller="ctrl.CtrlParties">
```

Those strong line above are red after the build. I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Could this be because of a missing plugin for IntelliJ? I think I had similar exception and found that I was missing this plugin in the IDE.